# ~/.bashrc script not run correctly on ssh login, does work correctly with source ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash, login, bashrc

To keep track of which ssh connection I have open in different tabs I use the following ~/.bashrc script:

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$@\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
set-title <SERVERNAME>;
echo "set-title <SERVERNAME>"
```

I do this for my tabs that I don't have ssh open (with `set-title LOCAL;`) and on two different servers. On one server it does exactly what I want to do and changes the tab name, but on the other server it does not change.

When I type `set-title <SERVERNAME>;` on the command line myself it does change the tab name, and when logging in it does echo `"set-title <SERVERNAME>"`. Also, if I do `source ~/.bashrc` it works as expected, so it is only when logging in to the server that it does not work.

On the server where it works on login runs `Scientific Linux release 6.7 (Carbon)`, on the server where it does not work runs `CentOS release 6.6 (Final)`. What could cause the `set-title <SERVERNAME>;` in the .bashrc script to not run correctly on login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further information, it’s not possible to answer this question.

However, I imagine the most likely scenario is that the `.bashrc` is sourced by on login by `.bash_profile` or `.profile` – probably something similar to this:

```
# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

I’d guess that on the system where the title isn’t being set, the `PS` variable is being set to another value at a later stage in the logon script.

The `PS1` variable should really be set in the Bash profile (`.bash_profile` or `.profile`) which is only run on login and the variable should be `exported`ed as an environment variable so that its value is inherited by any sub-shells.

```
PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
export PS1
```

or to use a short-hand that works for the Bash shell:

```
export PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
```